# Is there a way to print the variable name of an array as a string? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic

I am attempting to collect the variable name of an array without pre-defining said name as a seperate string.

So if you have `const someArray = ['cow', 'cheese', 'big_cow', 'big_cheese'];`

Is there a way to make a new variable, say `let arrayNameString`, that ends up being equal to `'someArray'` dynamically?

I noticed some partial solutions utilized mapping the keys of a newly defined object as well as `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` but I couldn't quite figure out how to translate that to my particular dynamic use-case.

Comment: No, there's no pointers back from objects to variables, it's a one-way reference. What would you expect if two variables refer to the same array?

Comment: If you think you need this, there's something wrong with your design. What are you really trying to do that requires getting the variable name from the array?

Comment: You could use an object, like `const someArray = {name: "someArray", data: ['cow', 'cheese', 'big_cow', 'big_cheese']};`

Comment: I am converting my dataset arrays to a CSV file, where the column names are equivalent to the array names, I'm trying to figure out if its possible to just have the name listed a single time instead of writing ```this.arrayName``` and ```'arrayName'``` every time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874128/5067233 for my current solution.

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating names with consecutive numbers in them, you should just be using an array and indexes, not names.

Comment: That was for the sake of example, it has specific arbitrary names.

Comment: use an object whose properties are the column names, not an array. Then you can use `Object.keys()` to get all the names.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I do this I make an object, as @Barmar suggested, but just use the name of the column as the key.

```
const data = { "arrayTitle" : [ 'data1', 'I\'m more data', 'etc.', 'etc.'] }
```

Then you can work accordingly using your loops to add data into the array:

```
// Add Data:
data["key"] = ['more data']
// or, provided the array already exists
data["key"].push('more things')

// Access Data:
for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
   const dataItem = data[key]
}
```

Using this structure should be more than enough to transform into a CSV.